# Dagger.android UserScope

Tags: android, dagger

I'm trying to create UserScope with https://google.github.io/dagger/android I have `@Singleton`, `@ActivityScope`, `@FragmentScope` and `@UserScope`.

**AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(
  modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ActivityBindingModule::class,
    AppModule::class,
    ApiModule::class
  ]
)
interface AppComponent {

  fun inject(application: Application)

  fun createUserComponent(): UserComponent.Builder

  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {

    @BindsInstance
    fun application(app: Application): Builder

    fun apiModule(module: ApiModule): Builder

    fun build(): AppComponent
  }
}
```

**UserComponent:**

```
@UserScope
@Subcomponent(
  modules = [UserModule::class]
)
interface UserComponent {

  @Subcomponent.Builder
  interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun user(user: User): Builder

    fun build(): UserComponent
  }
}
```

**UserModule:**

```
@Module
class UserModule {

  @UserScope
  @Provides
  fun provideUser(user: User): User = user
}
```

Here is how I am creating `UserComponent` after successfull login:

```
 private fun createSession(user: User) {    
      userComponent = appComponent.createUserComponent().user(user).build()
  }
```

And also I have UserManager which is triggering an issue with `User` injection constructor param

```
@UserScope
class SomeManager @Inject constructor(
    private val apiService: ApiService,
    private val user: User
) {}
```

> Error message: Error:[dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)]
>   domain.model.authorize.User cannot be provided without an @Inject
>   constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
>
> di.modules.MainActivityBindingModule_ContributeUserFragment.UserFragmentSubcomponent
>   scoped with @di.scopes.FragmentScope may not reference bindings with
>   different scopes: @di.scopes.UserScope class
>   domain.managers.SomeManager

I want to create `@UserScope` to manage related `ApiManagers` lifecycle

### UPD

```
@Module
class UserFragmentModule {

  @Provides
  @FragmentScope
  fun provideViewModelFactory(someModule: SomeModule) = UserFragmentViewModelFactory(someModule)
}
```

**ContributesAndroidInjector logic:**

```
@Module
interface ActivityBindingModule {

  @ActivityScope
  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SplashModule::class])
  fun contributeSplashActivity(): SplashActivity

  @ActivityScope
  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SignInModule::class])
  fun contributeAuthorizeActivity(): Activity

  @ActivityScope
  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainModule::class])
  fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity
}


@Module(includes = [MainActivityBindingModule::class])
class MainModule


@Module
interface MainActivityBindingModule {

  @FragmentScope
  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [UserFragmentModule::class])
  fun contributeUserFragment(): UserFragment
}
```

Comment: Care to share `UserFragmentSubcomponent`?

Comment: @azizbekian, this is autogenerated class. But anyway here it is https://codeshare.io/21Zwl0

Comment: @azizbekian, any suggestions? ))

Comment: Can you share `UserModule` also? There should be a dependency `SomeManager`, that is scoped with `@UserScope`, which is not possible, as long as `UserFragmentSubcomponent` has scope `@FragmentScope`. Secondly, there does not exist a provider method for `User` object.

Comment: @azizbekian, UserModule is present in the text. I've been added `UserFragmentModule` that is under the `@FragmentScope` but using `SomeManager` as a dependency. I tried to make `UserFragment` as subcomponent of the `UserComponent` but have an issue with an injection of `DispatchingAndroidInjector` in the `Application` class  because I need to have both injectors for `@Singleton` and `@UserScope`

Comment: provide the code of your `Application` as well as the `Activity` or `Fragment` in which you'd like to inject your user

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to inject a `User` instance that is provided only in the `@UserScope` in `@FragmentScope`.

Basically, the rule is whenever you need a `User` injected - you need to be in the `@UserScope`.

You need to change your `@FragmentScope` to `@UserScope` annotation in all places like that.

From what you posted I believe it is here:

```
@Module
class UserFragmentModule {

  @Provides
  @UserScope
  fun provideViewModelFactory(someModule: SomeModule) = UserFragmentViewModelFactory(someModule)
}
```

And you'll need to move your `UserFragmentModule` to the `UserComponent`:

```
@UserScope
@Subcomponent(
  modules = [UserModule::class, UserFragmentModule::class]
)
interface UserComponent {
```

And you'll also need to inject with `application.userComponent` into your `UserFragment`

Here is a good [article about subcomponents](https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-part-ii-custom-scopes-component-dependencies-subcomponents-697c1fa1cfc). I'd recommend you to read it to gain full understanding.

Another option, I'm not sure about this one, but maybe you can just inject your UserFragment with your `application.userComponent`.

Comment: Not sure how "you'll also need to inject with application.userComponent into your UserFragment" is different from "you can just inject your UserFragment with your application.userComponent"

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is wrong use of scopes.
Scopes help us to handle injected item life-cycle to prevent keep un-needed object in whole app life cycle.

[image]

and take look at this image:

[image]

Your modules should be in same scope that your component is.
for example in your `AppComponent`, you have `ActivityBindingModule` that have `ActivityScope`. why you do this?

I think it is better to have a `activityComopnent` that have dependency to`appComponent`. If your activityComponent had some dependency in upper scoped component (appComponent), first you had add dependency of that component. (`dependencies= [ AppComponent::class]`). Second, you had to expose needed dependency in appComponent with a method that return needed dependency object. Finally in wireUpping you should call appComponent as call activity modules in Dagger wire upping. ( I will show this in a example) 
So all you need is activityComponent like this:

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(modules = [ActivityBindingModule::class],dependencies= [ AppComponent::class])
interface activityComponent {
.
.
.
```

This is my example written in java that shows how connect **appComponent** and **activityComponent**:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class ,ServicesModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

void inject(ImicoApplication imicoApplication);

// exposed for child-components.
Context getContext();
Application getApplication();
CompanyService getCompanyService();
CategoryService getCategoryService();
RatingService getRatingService();
NewsService getNewsService();
AuthorizationManager getAuthorizationManager();
}
```

And this is **activityComponent**:

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class},modules = {SearchActivityModule.class})
public interface SearchserviceComponent {

    void inject (SearchFragment searchFragment);
}
```

And in SearchFragment do this for wire-up:

```
DaggerSearchserviceComponent.builder()
        .applicationComponent(((ImicoApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getApplicationComponent())
        .searchActivityModule(new SearchActivityModule(this)).build().inject(this);
```

If in SearchFragment i need **CompanyService** just inject it and it is provided and exposed by `applicationComponent`.

Comment: "for example in your AppComponent, you have ActivityBindingModule that have ActivityScope. why you do this?" - not true, that scope is applied to generated subcomponents (that are used to inject activities)